# In SQL can I convert column to rows?

Tags: sql, ms-access

specifically in MS ACCESS, exist a command o function as pivot unpivot work? in these case how can i do to convert using standar SQL...

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Convert column to row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560621/sql-convert-column-to-row)

Comment: This question has been asked a number of different times.  I have probably seen the question at least once or twice a week.  Do a search? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=column+to+rows

Comment: it's possible in ACCESS?

Comment: This question is by no means a duplicate of the suggested question.

Answer (score 1):

In Access, the simplest way is to use a crosstab query. There is a wizard, but please ask if you need more information.